# Problema com Programação Android. FOR

Tags: java, android

Não consigo gerar a quantidade de `EditTexts` baseado no parâmetro do `for`? Onde está o erro?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);



    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutEdits);

    int qtd = getIntent().getIntExtra("ValorDados", 0);
    vetorEdits = new EditText[qtd];

    for (int i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {

        vetorEdits[i] = new EditText(Main4Activity.this);
        vetorEdits[i].setHint("Valor do Edit " + (i+1));

        layout.addView(vetorEdits[i], new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    }
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro ? Se sim qual ? Se não qual o comportamento que apresenta ?

Comment: Aparece somente 1 EditText

Comment: Talvez porque `qtd = 1`

Comment: @ramaral Era precisamente o que ia dizer. Confirme o valor que tem em `qtd` fazendo `Log` de `qtd` antes de entrar no `for`. Se possível coloque até um print disso na pergunta

Comment: Consegui. O problema estava no XML. Obrigado a todos.